# "Expected subtree parent to be a mounted class component. " after extracting component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component (a form) which is based on office ui fabric. The form is working fine in my react application. However, since we need this at multiple places, we decided to make it an npm package.

I extracted the component and can implement it in my app. I can fill out textfields and save and it works properly. However, as soon as I open a dropdown or datepicker (basically a "Callout" from office ui fabric), I get the following error message:

"Expected subtree parent to be a mounted class component. This error is likely caused by a bug in React. Please file an issue."

and:

"react-dom.development.js:14227 The above error occurred in the  component:
    in LayerBase
    in CustomizedLayer
    in StyledCustomizedLayer
    in Callout
    in div
    in NormalPeoplePicker
[...]
"

Since it is working when I implement it within my app directly, it must be something in the build process I think. Can anybody eloberate, what this error message means exactly?

I am using the same package versions in my component as on my app.

Can I provide any files that might help? I don't know if showing my webpack.config or package.json for my component help at all?

Comment: A peek at the `webpack.config`, `package.json` and basic project structure could be helpful. I found that your error is only ever thrown at in the `findCurrentUnmaskedContext` function in  [react-reconciler](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/c954efa70f44a44be9c33c60c57f87bea6f40a10/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberContext.js). It seems that react wants to "unmask" a component but the supplied component isn't a ClassComponent. I hope that makes sense to you.

Comment: Thank you it definetly took me on the right track. See my answer below for the solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, it was indeed a mistake in my build process. I bundled the node_modules with my component and therefore suddenly hat two react "instances". After installing webpack-node-externals and adding

```
externals: [nodeExternals()]
```

to my webpack.config it works now.